# What is the correct name for this "door stopper"?

Tags: repair, doors, safety, child-safety

I would like to mount something on my doors, so they can't slam shut when the wind catches them. When I search for "door stoppers" I never get such.

I have only been able to find on company that makes such "Arte Viva", but surely they can't be the only ones.

Does anyone know what such really are called?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cabinets, those are soft close stops or dampers.  Try the same for entry doors.

Comment: Yep.  Door soft close damper.